# Sublime Build use in Windows. Run a PHP script from Sublime

Tags: php, sublimetext2

I am trying to get the sublime build system working for PHP using windows. I watched [this video](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/custom-builds/) which is great; but his demonstration is on a Mac and it doesn't seem to be possible to do the same thing on windows using his techniques; at least I wasn't able to run a PHP file from the command line in the same way he was on the Mac using terminal. He makes no mention of needing to use WAMP or MAMP either but I use Wamp myself.

Ultimately what I am trying to do is to run a PHP file directly within Sublime like he does in the video. Is this possible and if so how? I am on Windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer on [this page](http://www.xcjs.com/2012/01/02/adding-a-php-build-system-to-sublime-text-2/)

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.2.6\\php.exe", "$file"]
}
```